# Modular Jquery SPA (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, rest

I have looked over the web and found some cool examples of MVC implementation in the JQuery world. Some seems "outdated" (or maybe, not...), but looked promising:

- [CorMVC](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/projects/cormvc/demo/index.htm#/) (2-3 years ago)
- [Adam Wulf tutorial](http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/) (3-4 years ago)

And more recent (that I have found):

- [Pirek GITHUB](https://github.com/dpirek/jQuery-MVC-Framework) (one year ago)
- [todoMVC](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/master/architecture-examples/jquery) : Code seems pretty neat. But there's no separation (folders).

**I was wondering if there was more complete example of an MVC infrastructure/framework for implementing a SPA website (and recent, working with the latest version of JQuery)**. I am trying to build that on top of [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and for the backend, I am using rest in Perl.

I have checked various [javascript framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) (note that I come from a Ruby on Rails world). I have played with various one:

GWT:

- Pros: I liked the fact that I was only coding java and "easy" implement of various design pattern of course.
- Cons: Debugging time (so slow to run your application).

Dojo:

- Pros: Custom Widget, Modular (OOP concepts)
- Cons: Complex, Poor community, Poor documentation, Poor example. I have read all documentation, but when it comes to put it altogether I was so confuse and lost.

Now, I am really tempted by Jquery/[JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). With my background (RoR/MVC/Java), I think it's a pretty decent/neat framework or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Backbone (haven't met a JS dev who doesn't like backbone) + Handlebars templates (handlebars is way better than mustache). It's not true MVC but it's very lightweight and flexible. If you need more power there are true MVC layers on top of backbone (can't find them right now, they have dumb names) which are also fairly small. All of these things combined are still probably half the size of JavascriptMVC.

GWT is meh (haven't met many people who like it, have met many who don't, plus it's Java), Dojo is feh (very large codebase, small community).

Comment: I'm having a look at backbone and I like it too! I just need a little bit more time understanding everything, but just by knowing that there's this CRUD example(http://coenraets.org/backbone-cellar/bootstrap/#). I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: https://marionettejs.com/ is a great wrapper for backbone

Answer (score 1):

I built something with a combination of jquery, jsviews (http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html) and RequireJS.  In the end, the RequireJS was a bit of a learning curve, but once I got used to it I found it was a very powerful mechanism.  I'm not sure on the current status of jsviews, so I might use handlebars if I had to do it again.  When I looked at it, I didn't really like backbone for what I was doing, if I'd been working on more of a data drive (as opposed to primarily visual) application then I might have used it.